# Nsuserdefauls problem

Tags: iphone

I have typed the coding under the highscore button. It is suppose to string the text(name) in the textbox and save the highscore. However, i could not find any plist being created under the document. Please help

```
-(IBAction)savehighscore_button {


 int i, ii = -1;

 struct high_score {
  NSString *name;
  int highScore;
 };

 struct high_score structArray[10];

 NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 for (i=0; i<10; i++) {

  if ([userPreferences stringForKey :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreNameEntry%d",i]]!=nil && [userPreferences stringForKey :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreEntry%d"]]!=nil) {
  structArray[i].name= [userPreferences stringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreNameEntry%d",i]];
   structArray[i].highScore = [userPreferences integerForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreEntry%d",i]];
   ii = i;
  }
 }
 if (myScore >0) {
  for (i==ii; i>=0; i--) {
   if (myScore > structArray[i].highScore) {
    if (i<9) {
     structArray[i+1] = structArray[i];
     structArray[i].name = nametextbox.text;
     structArray[i].highScore = myScore;

     if (i==ii && i<9) {
      structArray[i+1].name = nametextbox.text;
      structArray[i+1].highScore = myScore;
      ii=i+i;
     }

     else if(i==ii && i<9) {
      structArray[i+1].name = nametextbox.text;
      structArray[i+1].highScore = myScore;
      ii=i+1;
     }
    }
   }

   if (ii==-1 && myScore >0) {
    structArray[0].name = nametextbox.text;
    structArray[0].highScore = myScore;
    ii=0;
   }
   for (i=0; i<=ii; i++) {
    [userPreferences setObject:structArray[i].name forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreNameEntry%d",i]];
    [userPreferences setInteger:structArray[i].highScore forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreEntry%d",i]];
   }
  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writablePlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"My.plist"];

if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:writablePlistPath]){
        BOOL success;
        NSString *defaultPlistPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"My.plist"];
        success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:defaultPlistPath toPath:writablePlistPath error:nil];
               //for getting content of plist
        pListArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:writablePlistPath];
}
```

This code used for saving your plist in document directory so first time(at launch app first time on simulator or device) save your pList in document directory then you can access data of plist.by the same code change occur in if condition only ! opertor should not be there and pListArray have your pList data so you can access via this array.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` are not saved to the Documents folder on iOS. You can tell if the user defaults were saved successfully simply by trying `objectForKey:` and friends. Generally speaking, you should have no need to know where they are or how the data is structured on disk. If you need functionality like that, use `NSKeyedArchiver` instead.