# Data not save in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone

i having a problem with my NSUserdefaults. When i type in the name in the textbox and click on the highscore the application will not response anything and the keypad will still be on the screen. When i tried to load the data, it say that the data for name is nil. The score that i have is 90. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my coding.

Lots of thanks.

```
-(IBAction)savehighscore_button {


    int i, ii = -1;

    struct high_score {
        NSString *name;
        int highScore;
    };

    struct high_score structArray[10];

    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {

        if ([userPreferences stringForKey :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreNameEntry%d",i]]!=nil && [userPreferences stringForKey :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreEntry%d"]]!=nil) {
        structArray[i].name= [userPreferences stringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreNameEntry%d",i]];
            structArray[i].highScore = [userPreferences integerForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreEntry%d",i]];
            ii = i;
        }
    }
    if (myScore >0) {
        for (i==ii; i>=0; i--) {
            if (myScore > structArray[i].highScore) {
                if (i<9) {
                    structArray[i+1] = structArray[i];
                    structArray[i].name = nametextbox.text;
                    structArray[i].highScore = myScore;

                    if (i==ii && i<9) {
                        structArray[i+1].name = nametextbox.text;
                        structArray[i+1].highScore = myScore;
                        ii=i+i;
                    }

                    else if(i==ii && i<9) {
                        structArray[i+1].name = nametextbox.text;
                        structArray[i+1].highScore = myScore;
                        ii=i+1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (ii==-1 && myScore >0) {
                structArray[0].name = nametextbox.text;
                structArray[0].highScore = myScore;
                ii=0;
            }
            for (i=0; i<=ii; i++) {
                [userPreferences setObject:structArray[i].name forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreNameEntry%d",i]];
                [userPreferences setInteger:structArray[i].highScore forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"highScoreEntry%d",i]];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hi carl, may i know which part u edited.

Comment: he fixed ur broken code formatting

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320756/nsuserdefauls-problem/4320827

Comment: Ya, but now the problem is the application will freeze after i click the highscore button. I have no idea what is wrong. The application still freeze even after i used the edited code

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions, qiQi. Wait patiently for an answer or try to clarify your original question.

Comment: i am sorry for that. But this is the real error that i found out just now. the other post was posted damn long ago.

Comment: 16 hours is not "damn long ago" and you should *still* post updates to your original question. People will start ignoring you if you don't follow the rules.

Comment: ok sorry. i will not repeat that again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything saved into user defaults must be of a [standard PLIST-compliant class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2) (NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSValue). If it's not one of those, it has to be archived as an NSData instance (and therefore be NSCoding compliant) or packed into an NSValue if it's compatible.

That said, you're making this far more difficult on yourself than you need to. Why not have an array (the high score descriptor container) of dictionaries (each is a descriptor for a high score) that hold a name (an NSString) and the score (an NSNumber)? Each dictionary describes a high score for a given name. You can then store the whole thing by using `-setObject:yourArray forKey:@"HighScores"`.

Since you only get immutable copies back from NSUserDefaults, you'll want to ask for a -mutableCopy of the high scores array (don't forget to release it) when you want to modify things. Either replace a score or delete/add.

Using this approach, you don't have to resort to the (sorry for this) *ghastly* "string#" approach with a fixed number of scores. Your array will only contain the existing high scores. No waste and all 100% standard Cocoa classes that are fully PLIST'able with no extra work. This also lets you easily sort the array using sort descriptors (sorted by the key you used to store the score number in the dictionary).

Some basic code:

```
/* Build a fake high scores array */

NSMutableArray * highScores = [NSMutableArray array];

// Bob's score
NSDictionary * bob = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Bob", @"name", 
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:8234323], @"score", 
        nil];
[highScores addObject:bob];

// Jane's score
NSDictionary * jane = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Jane", @"name", 
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:92346345], @"score", 
        nil];
[highScores addObject:jane];

// Donald's score
NSDictionary * donald = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Donald", @"name", 
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:5272348], @"score", 
        nil];
[highScores addObject:donald];

// Sort by high score
NSSortDescriptor * sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"score" 
                                                      ascending:NO];
[highScores sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[sort release];

// Store in user defaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:highScores 
                                          forKey:@"HighScores"];
```

Comment: thanks, do you have any website with the above method that i can use as refer. i am sorry cause i am new to this programming language.

Comment: How about the link I provided in the first sentence? Beyond that, you'll have to ask more specific questions. I don't know of any guides to do exactly what you're looking for - your google search is as good as mine.

Comment: the link to the first sentence was post by me. Thus, the coding still have the same error. as i have find out that data are not save after using the help given from the link

Comment: I meant the first sentence of *my answer*. The text "standard PLIST-compliant class" is linked to the exact page of the documentation that explains the property-list-compatible classes and how to use property lists (which is what preferences are stored in).

Comment: I have edited the coding but the program still cannot work, do you mind tell me what is wrong.

Comment: NSString *name;
 
 name = nametextbox.text;
 
 NSDictionary *player = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name], @"name",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myScore], @"score",nil];
 [highScore addObject:player];
 
 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"score" ascending:NO];
 [highScore sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
 [sort release];
 
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:highScore forKey:@"highScore"];

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? **Details.** Two things I notice. First, you don't have to use stringWithFormat: as name is already a string. Second, you've completely ignored the use of NSNumber to store your score. Why would you convert it to a string for storage?

Comment: The data is saved into the NSUserDefaults but when i tried to load the NSUserDefaults, it will return with value out of scope.

Comment: loadhighScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavehighScore"];

Comment: You really need to provide more details. WHAT returns with value out of scope? On what line of code? If you make it too hard to help you, people will give up.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to use:

```
[userPreferences synchronize];
```